# How to get client real ip on Nginx server

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, nginx, devops

I have an issue when i try to get client ip, it gives same ip address for every client. I added these lines to my nginx.conf file:

```
set_real_ip_from  127.0.0.1;
set_real_ip_from  0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1;
set_real_ip_from  192.168.56.1;
real_ip_header    X-Forwarded-For;
real_ip_recursive on;
     
#proxy_set_header Host $host;                                   
#proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;                      
#proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;  
(I am not sure to add this part.)
```

But it still not working. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
```

https://serverfault.com/a/377212

Comment: When I added the real ip module to nginx and this code to the conf file, it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to obtain client ipaddress on Spring Boot, you need to set `server.forward-headers-strategy` to `native`.

`application.properties`:

```
server.forward-headers-strategy=native
```

- [9.3.12. Running Behind a Front-end Proxy Server](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-behind-a-proxy-server)